# Maven components not working on Windows Server

Tags: java, windows, maven, tomcat, server

I have a Maven project (a Tomcat 8 application) that works fine in my laptop in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. Recently I started working on a Windows Server. I downloaded the project from GitHub and istalled on the server properly. But some things don't seem to work quite right. 
For example, the application can't find some html files (I haven't hardcoded any paths) and some functions don't work properly.
I was wondering if there are compatibility issues with Maven or Tomcat and Windows Server 2013. If not, what could the problem be in this situation?

Comment: Any error message on building the project on the server?

Comment: Windows has a case-insensitive file system, on a non-windows systems or used from a .war / .jar everything is **case-sensitive**. It could be that you are now not unpacking the war or such. And then there is the **character encoding** that could differ. Check the paths.

Comment: No, no error messages. There's one more thing. The tests works when run seperately from the project but they don't when I run then after build. I'm going to check the encoding. @JoopEggen I don't understand the first part of your comment.

Comment: It is clear I think that when running (say) a jar, the a resource path `"A.jpg"`  cannot find a resource `a.jpg` - which it would under Windows using the unpacked path of classes. The IDE could also mess up class paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It was a matter of the path it was running on. I added a SystemPath attribute and it works fine. Thanks for the answers.